# Is there any evidence that this character survived X-Men: Apocalypse?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-apocalypse

In X-Men Apocalypse, is there any evidence that:

> Apocalypse

survived

> his major beat down at the hands of the X-Men

?

Comment: According to [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Men:_Apocalypse): "_Finally, Xavier encourages Jean to unleash the full extent of her powers, incinerating En Sabah Nur's body... **apparently casting him to the astral plane.**_" Although I can't recall the scene as I have only seen it once.

Comment: @user35594 You should make that into an answer, so I can upvote it.

Comment: Thanks but not sure if it's enough to be considered an answer. I've asked a question on [meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9809/should-a-comment-referenced-from-wiki-be-posted-as-an-answer) to find out what the correct protocol is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### We have no knowledge of the full extent of X-Men: Apocalypse's [En Sabah Nur's](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/En_Sabah_Nur_(Earth-616)) abilities. Since he has gathered and transferred the mutant abilities of dozens of mutants in the past, we cannot be certain even complete physical destruction of his body meant the destruction of his incredibly powerful mind.

If the comic version of the character is any indication, this would be a setback but hardly the end of the character. His powers indicate as long as a single cell of him exists, he can reconstitute himself again.

#### In X-Men: Apocalypse

- Given the nature of his powers and how he acquired them, it is the very nature of his powerful mind and psychic essence, to be able to be transferred from body to body for centuries (with the appropriate technology) which makes me believe he not dead, but that it may be possible to actually kill him permanently. Unlike his comic analog, he may boast a degree of psychic immortality rather than a physical one.
- Given that the technology which allowed him to move from body to body continues to exist into the present day. It may be possible to reintegrate him into another receptive mutant body, re-establishing himself (as well as taking over the body of the mutant foolish enough to allow him to inhabit them in the first place.

Given his the unknown nature of his powers, his potentially fantastic range of abilities and the existence of a technology he has used for centuries to body swap, the death of his current body is certainly a loss and it may be a while before he can return to life, but the possibility of his return is well within the boundaries of the genre, given the porous nature of the afterlife, especially for powerful villains.

**Side note:** He does have a body just sitting around waiting to inhabit remember? It is presupposed Angel is dead. Having some measure of Apocalypse's power used to recreate his body and its metallic wings, Angels body would make the perfect haven for the spiritual essence of Apocalypse to hide out in and recover, now wouldn't it... Ironic, given his disposition when Angel died. Apocalypse called him a weakling...